# Mass Effect 3 Ammo Types

Tags: mass-effect-3

I continually find ammo packs on the ground and I will be low on one type of ammo, but when I go over to it, it tell me my ammo is full. How do I tell between the different types of ammo lying around so I know which ones I need and which ones I don't need to run over to try and pick up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ammo packs on the ground will refill some percentage of all of your weapon's ammo, regardless of type. They will refill ammo for weapons that you've got holstered, as well as your active weapon.  The exception seems to be certain "heavy weapons" like the Krogan flamethrower.

I haven't worked out exactly how much they refill, but when you get the "Ammo Full" message, all your reserve ammo is full on all of your weapons.

Comment: clips restore different amounts for different weapons.

Comment: Hmm, I could've sworn that my sniper rifle didn't refill when I got ammo. But I just tested it and it seemed to work fine. Must have been an illusion of battle. Good to know about the heavy weapons though.

Comment: @RavenDreamer, is it a percentage of total ammo?  I haven't worked it out completely.  I keep meaning to SCIENCE! it.

Comment: @agent86 I'm sitting at a spot where I can science a little bit. I'll see what I come up with :)

Comment: @Ktash, I asked a different question for this, since it's kind of different from what you asked: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54944

Comment: @agent86 Alright, I will report my findings there.