# How much ammo does picking up a single clip refill?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When I pick up extra ammo off of fallen enemies or laying around the environment, it refills some amount of the ammo in all of my equipped weapons.

How much ammo does each additional clip refill?  Is it a percentage of the total ammo for each weapon?  Does it vary depending on weapon type or model?  Is there any difference between the ammo refill rate of my active weapon and my reserve weapons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single ammo clip has the following effects on all weapons at these difficulties:

- Very Easy: 40% ammo fill
- Easy: 40% ammo fill
- Normal: 40% ammo fill
- Hard: 30% ammo fill
- Insane: 20% ammo fill

These values are pulled directly from the ME3 coalesced settings file. Note that in the event of a decimal value, it will round *down*, not to the nearest value. Others, however, have reported that this doesn't necessarily translate to [all weapons](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/M-98_Widow) but I have been unable to confirm this, and it is not in the coalesced settings file that I could see.

Also, it will fill your grenades in the following manner:

- Very Easy: 10 grenades
- Easy: 3 grenades
- Normal: 2 grenades
- Hard: 1 grenade
- Insane: 1 grenade

All guns in need of ammo will receive the full amount of a single reload clip (eg all guns will be refilled by 40% on normal difficulty).

Also note that ammo will respawn given enough time, so if you are really in need of some ammo, camping a spot will can easily refill your gun.

Comment: This is demonstrably incorrect. See this link http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/M-98_Widow

Comment: @kotekzot Interesting. I will revise this than.

Comment: @Kotekzot Those values don't seem to be updated for ME3. For example, the maximum ammo capacity for the [M-3 Predator](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/M-3_Predator) is wrong. I will go through and check this as I go along and update my answer for exceptions when I get a new weapon, but I'm not very far in the game, so I can't do it for all weapons at the moment.

Comment: That is possible, however the Widow certainly does get 1 or 2 shots per thermal clip, I've tested this.

Comment: @kotekzot Interesting. Well, I will add that as an exception on my list than. If you can come up with a more precise number (unless it actually varies) that would be helpful.

Comment: A precise number for what?

Comment: @kotekzot How much ammo it actually gets from picking up an ammo clip.

Comment: What's it? The Widow? 1 or 2 shots exactly. Different weapons get different amount of shots per clip.

Answer (score 0):

Each weapon has a minimum and maximum number of shots that may be refilled by a single clip. A high-powered sniper rifle may get 1 or 2 shots, while an assault rifle will get dozens.

Comment: it also seems to depend on how close to empty your ammo count is, or maybe that's just my imagination